# Run a java program in shell script

Tags: java, shell, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [run a java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799172/run-a-java-program)

Hi guys

I want to run a java program using shell script. The java program is in p2 directory and its name is maxconnect4. I write the shell commands like this:

java p2/maxconnect4 arg1 arg2 arg3

This shell command does not work.

However, I compile the java program in this way:

javac p2/*.java, and it works.

Thanks in advanced

Zhong