# run a java program

Tags: java, shell, command

I want to run a java program using shell script. The java program is in p2 directory and its name is maxconnect4 and I have already compiled it, the class name is maxconnect4. I write the shell commands like this:

java p2/maxconnect4 arg1 arg2 arg3

This shell command does not work.
It give an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: p2/maxconnect

However, I compile the java program in this way:

javac p2/*.java, and it works.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it doesn't work?  What error messages are you getting?

Comment: The error is:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: p2/maxconnect4/class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `java -cp p2 maxconnect4 arg1 arg2 arg3`. -cp  sets the classpath of the JVM. Edit: I assume you don't use a package for maxconnect4.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the class has `package p2;` declared, that should work -- although the more standard way is to use dots instead of slashes in the fully-qualified classname -- `java p2.maxconnect`.

If the class has no package declaration, try `java -cp p2 maxconnect`.  You need to specify a classpath such that the class file is found at the top level.

If the class has some other package declaration, you need to put it into a folder that matches its package.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
java p2.maxconnect4 arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Also, you can try to check the class name, and verify if the file p2/maxconnect4.class exists.